# PHP in_array function doesn't find value

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP variable:

```
$values = $response->getValues();
```

That print this array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 16777439-3 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 17425847-3 ) )
```

Then I have this code to find a value inside of that array:

```
if (in_array("16777439-3", $values)) {

    echo "Is in array";

}else{

    echo "Isn't in array";

}
```

But all the time it returns "**Isn't in array**"

Also I've tried to convert my original variable with:

```
$array2 = json_decode(json_encode($values), true);
```

But also I'm getting the same return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a multi-dimensional array, so just extract the `0` columns with `array_column`:

```
if (in_array("16777439-3", array_column($values, 0))) {
    echo "Is in array";
} else {
    echo "Isn't in array";
}
```

Or flatten the array with `array_merge`:

```
if (in_array("16777439-3", array_merge(...$array))) {
    echo "Is in array";
} else {
    echo "Isn't in array";
}
```

Also, checking if an index `isset` is faster, so you can just re-index on the `0` value and check if that index is set:

```
if (isset(array_column($values, null, 0)["16777439-3"])) {
    echo "Is in array";
} else {
    echo "Isn't in array";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all your help and explanation! Finally I got it! ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your values array looks like this:

```
[
  0 => [
         0 => "16777439-3"
       ],
  1 => [
         0 => "17425847-3"
       ]
]
```

Your top level elements are arrays themselves. `in_array` can't do a nested search like this. It would only work if your array was just

```
[
  0 => "16777439-3"
  1 => "17425847-3"
]
```

Either change your structure to not use a nested array, or implement a custom search function:

```
function custom_in_array($search, $haystack){
    foreach($haystack as $key => $value)
    {
        if(in_array($search, $value))
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$values is an array of arrays, not an array of strings.

To illustrate, try :

```
if (in_array("16777439-3", $values[0] )) {

    echo "Is in array";

}else{

    echo "Isn't in array";

}
```

You'll have to to some processing to convert $response->getValues() into an array of strings